# html display inline text in table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display some text in the bottom left of my table but having some issues getting that. What can I try to get that to display?

[image]

```css
.table_b10 {
  width: 10cm;
  height: 2cm;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.heading2_b10 {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_b10">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="heading2_b10">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="heading2_b10">LADIES STOCKINGS SYN-BLACK</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can `colspan` attribute help you in this case?

```css
.table_b10 {
  width: 10cm; 
  height: 2cm; 
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
}
  
heading2_b09 {
  font-family:calibri; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 8;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading2_b10 {
  font-family:calibri; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  font-size: 11;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<table class="table_b10">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="heading2_b10" colspan="2">Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="heading2_b09">LOG-ID: ###</td>
            <td class="heading2_b10">LADIES STOCKINGS SYN-BLACK</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Explanation:** `colspan` attribute can be applied on a `<td>` element, it allows you to set how columns wide the element should be.

**What is changed?**
The first row has `colspan="2"`, that means his width will be extended to 2 columns, like the one under. But this one has really two columns to show where the `LOG-ID: ###` string is the first, aligned on the left and `LADIES STOCKINGS SYN-BLACK` one is the second

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest thing to do would be just to add `style="text-align:left;"` to the html tag's attribute